# JavaScript doesn't scroll at second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this part of code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#Div1").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
        $("#Button2").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#Div2").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
        $("#Button3").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#Div3").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I get to the page, and click one of the buttons works fine, but when I need to click again it don't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you could easily simplify this code so that you have one event listener control all the scrolling instead of having a separate click function for each button.

Comment: What does the html look like?

Answer (score 0):

It must have something to do with your HTML. I put your code in the snippet below and it works.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#Div1").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
        $("#Button2").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#Div2").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
        $("#Button3").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#Div3").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```

```css
.space {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Button1">Button1</button>
<button id="Button2">Button2</button>
<button id="Button3">Button3</button>


<div class="space"></div>
<div id="Div1">Div1</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="Div2">Div2</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="Div3">Div3</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="space"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks okay from my end, I've created this jsfiddle for you.

I believe, the button is not working because you might be already at the same place you want to scroll to.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nilegfx/pvdjskvw/)

**Code Snippet**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Button1").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#Div1").offset().top
     }, 2000);
   });
   $("#Button2").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#Div2").offset().top
     }, 2000);
   });
   $("#Button3").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#Div3").offset().top
     }, 2000);
   });
 });
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  
  
<div id="Div1">1</div>
<div id="Div2">2</div>
<div id="Div3">3</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="Button1">click1</div>
<div id="Button2">click2</div>
<div id="Button3">click3</div>
  
  
</body>
```